# Keeping a local mirror lean and mean for what our application needs

Tags: centos, cache, rpm, package-management, mirror

We have a local mirror RPM repositorythat lives where our virtual servers live on Amazon Web Services. This setup could conserve some network bandwidth, but my predecessor probably set it up as place for hand-rolled RPMS as additional reason.

We have the idea that RPMS that are not used should be cleaned out to quicken the time to rebuild an index.  Is there best practice around this?  I'm also wondering if an alternate approach of rebuilding the index more often would be better.